# How is yellow elastic cartilage a true cartilage?

Tags: tissue, cartilage

My book has only mentioned the fact but no reason is given so I would like to know the reason for it. I would like to know what more to add in the body but the question just doesn't get posted.[image]

Comment: What research have you done , have tried googling it atleast? Question which doesn't show attempt are likely to be deleted.

Comment: Yes i have already googled it even asked the same question but it always open wikipedia which donot provide me my answers

Comment: Could you cite the book?

Comment: A TEXT BOOK OF BIOLOGY

Comment: author name pls

Comment: Wikipedia **cartilage** defines it as being *composed of specialized cells called chondrocytes that produce a large amount of collagenous extracellular matrix, abundant ground substance that is rich in proteoglycan and elastin fibers.* , then states that: *Cartilage is classified in three types, elastic cartilage, hyaline cartilage and fibrocartilage, which differ in relative amounts of collagen and proteoglycan.* The term **elastic cartilage** links to a separate page describing elastic or yellow cartilage. What other information do you need?

Comment: Maybe he wants the reason why its called "true"

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=uIWU4x4Rq0cC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%22true+cartilage%22&source=bl&ots=GNYGWHvaR4&sig=O__pwHVGQjZEerZvASTSTbUDwOk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT87G7tJ7VAhUmTY8KHQOICyMQ6AEIQDAI#v=onepage&q=%22true%20cartilage%22&f=false

Comment: jm97 it the book i mentioned is by...Dr.Rameshwar p.singh,Dr.Shree krishna subedi,Mukti ram aryal and Dinesh chandra adhikari....and i what i want to know is mentioned in title

Answer (score 1):

True cartilage is something of a simplification or a misnomer, they are saying that it truly a form of cartilage and not another elastic tissue type. in fact 
"true cartilage" is a term coined by your book. They could have also said it's part of the cartilage family of cell/tissue types.

It's similar to cartilage under a microscope, structurally and has similar consituents, although yellow cartilage also contains elastin. If you were to dissect humans, you would probably find that there are a lot of variations of cartilage of different elasticity, midway in between both forms.

[this page is full of info and pics:](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=1193&bih=707&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=yellow%20cartilage%20microscope%20comparison&oq=yellow%20cartilage%20microscope%20comparison&gs_l=img.3...3408.5004.0.5315.11.10.0.0.0.0.176.886.0j6.6.0....0...1.1.64.img..5.0.0.kjeeMfo8l1w#imgdii=NBjrsXi64dxHzM:&imgrc=wZ8LN2ZBjYUgbM:)

It's a good idea to check wikipedia and 2-3 pages to find results to that kind of query, you will find fabulous resources, whereas on stack it is really for studies that take more than 20 minutes via google.